# Correctly adding a hat over i character in a Word office equation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equations, equation-editor

I've been trying on figuring out how to correctly insert an accent over the *i* character in a word equation.

For example, if i do: `i\hat`, i get: [image]

If i do: `i\above ^` i get [image], which is too far from the letter.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with your first example? This is what I would expect from the accented letter.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the font?

Comment: If you’re concerned by the absence of the dot above the “î” in the first example, it is in fact correct, even if it looks wrong to you. The accent replaces the dot.

Comment: If you do want an i with a dot and a circumflex, you could try force that by inserting the three codepoints U+0131 U+0307 U+0302, or ı̇̂ for short. Not sure how to do that in the equation editor though.

Comment: Yes, I am worried about the absence of the dot under the hat.

Comment: @harrymc, no matter which font i use, the dot doesn't appear under the hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a circumflex accent correctly by doing as you have done with `i\hat`. The lack of a dot above the "i" is the correct behaviour. [Multiple](https://www.lifewire.com/typing-characters-with-circumflex-accent-marks-1074102) [citations](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ee/index.htm) [here](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/accents). If you would prefer that Word incorrectly shows a dot as well as the accent, then that would be a different question, though I doubt that such behaviour is possible.